# Student is Already Exist Validation for Enrollment System (Codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, sql, codeigniter, validation

i'm newbie in coding, and i need some help how to make a validation in adding student and it will prompt the student is already exist, i have a sample codes here to create student and update. but i dont know how to validate it if the student is already exist when i add a student with the same full name. and i need to validate my email too if the email si already exist..

Thank you in advance.. hope you help me a lot.. :D

```
function student($param1 = '', $param2 = '', $param3 = '')
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') != 1)
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    if ($param1 == 'create') {
        $data['name']        = $this->input->post('name');
        $data['birthday']    = $this->input->post('birthday');
        $data['sex']         = $this->input->post('sex');
        $data['address']     = $this->input->post('address');
        $data['phone']       = $this->input->post('phone');
        $data['email']       = $this->input->post('email');
        $data['password']    = md5($this->input->post('password')); 
        $data['father_name'] = $this->input->post('father_name');
        $data['mother_name'] = $this->input->post('mother_name');
        $data['class_id']    = $this->input->post('class_id');
        $data['roll']        = $this->input->post('roll');
        $this->db->insert('student', $data);
        $student_id = mysql_insert_id();
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/student_image/' . $student_id . '.jpg');
        $this->email_model->account_opening_email('student', $data['email']); //SEND EMAIL ACCOUNT OPENING EMAIL
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('add_student_success'));
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/student/' . $data['class_id'], 'refresh');
    }
    if ($param2 == 'do_update') {
        $data['name']        = $this->input->post('name');
        $data['birthday']    = $this->input->post('birthday');
        $data['sex']         = $this->input->post('sex');
        $data['address']     = $this->input->post('address');
        $data['phone']       = $this->input->post('phone');
        $data['email']       = $this->input->post('email');
        $data['password']    = md5($this->input->post('password'));
        $data['father_name'] = $this->input->post('father_name');
        $data['mother_name'] = $this->input->post('mother_name');
        $data['class_id']    = $this->input->post('class_id');
        $data['roll']        = $this->input->post('roll');

        $this->db->where('student_id', $param3);
        $this->db->update('student', $data);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/student_image/' . $param3 . '.jpg');
        $this->crud_model->clear_cache();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('edit_student_success'));
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/student/' . $param1, 'refresh');
    } else if ($param2 == 'edit') {
        $page_data['edit_data'] = $this->db->get_where('student', array(
            'student_id' => $param3
        ))->result_array();
    } else if ($param2 == 'personal_profile') {
        $page_data['personal_profile']   = true;
        $page_data['current_student_id'] = $param3;
    } else if ($param2 == 'academic_result') {
        $page_data['academic_result']    = true;
        $page_data['current_student_id'] = $param3;
    }
    if ($param2 == 'delete') {
        $this->db->where('student_id', $param3);
        $this->db->delete('student');
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/student/' . $param1, 'refresh');
    }
    $page_data['class_id']   = $param1;
    $page_data['students']   = $this->db->get_where('student', array(
        'class_id' => $param1
    ))->result_array();
    $page_data['page_name']  = 'student';
    $page_data['page_title'] = get_phrase('manage_student');
    $this->load->view('index', $page_data);
}
```

Comment: I would not base the uniqueness of a student on their first name and last name, when i was teaching in London in one class I had two Alex Smith's and I bet the school had seen a few more over the years. If email is mandatory you could use that as two different people should never have the same email address.

Answer (score 1):

Please used this.

```
$firstName  = $this->input->post('firstName');
$lastName   = $this->input->post('lastName');

$checkStudentExists = $this->db->get_where('student', array('lastName' => $lastName, 'firstName' => $firstName);

if(count($checkStudentExists) > 0) {
  echo "Student already exists. Please enter another.";
} else {
# Do your code
}
```

Hope it helps. They are many lastnames and firstnames coexists, please add middlename or birthday for validation

Comment: Is it possible to `count $checkStudentExists` ?

Comment: thank you for you fast response and i appreciate it :D

im so sorry to say im so dumb in coding.. :(
where can i put your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi im gonna ask if this is correct in my validation code if the fullname is already exist..

```
$name  = $this->input->post('name');

$checkFullnameExists = $this->db->get_where('student', array('name' => $name,);
if(count($checkStudentExists) > 0) {
$this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('Student is already exists'));
} else {
#do your code
}
```

one more thing i need to validate the email too if the email is already exist.. many thanks @Shudmeyer...